# How to create a file from an http get response using Node + Express without setting the response type

Tags: node.js, express, jira-rest-api

I'm using axios to download files from a Jira Server, however when I set the request type to 'stream' the response from Jira states that I am not authenticated. When this is removed I received the following response (extract):

v�Ģ
�-���[�T��j�1c�N{�;&��o���Pvwf=���������P�V4�_�T�ݡ;�J$W� O��|��M\�Oʥ �L/t%��N���/|���g9i;��^���N��|1b�Q
                                                                                                       ڴ��q�
                                                                                                            ��ڤ�^��${o�'����[����vWD�cF\N�����?�zw�irer�z#p�f�T�L7�5H�w��A��,�q�#�����}V�)�+�6gO�3�5`$�}8"�bm���;��P�.�m?������zo  l�v�G)���,�E7id�JN}�[
                                                                                                     �r��Z���)�������o��F�ZN��O�FD���/�����G�QяD����mw��
M��0A��_0�&���Jî!�m����Za
�Q����������ƃ�S�����To��3`D     �#:��`g�]��|y%Fހ�s����D

using the code below:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/secure/attachmentzip/' + req.body.issue.id + ".zip",                             
                            {
                                auth: {
                                    username: '-',
                                    password: '-'
                                } 
                            }
                            )
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    console.log(response.data)
                                     })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                })
```

Is it possible to create a file based off the above response?

Comment: similar question ( img files / axios )  :: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js    so just swap zip for jpg to stream to your zip file

Comment: Yes use fs.writeFile() to write response.data to a file with a .zip extension

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thank you for the response, I can't use that method as it sets the request type. For some reason Jira does not allow the program to authenticate with the request type set.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez Thank you for the response, I've tried using fs.writeFile() with the following encodings 'Binary', 'utf-8', 'hex' to no avail. Do you perhaps know the encoding I should use? Sorry if I come across as naive, this is the first time I've dealt with files.

Comment: @The_flash check out Marcos Casagrande's answer below. This is exactly how I have done it in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with files or binary data, I had several issues in the past using `axios`, I recommend using `request`, `request-promise` or `got`

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

request.get('http://localhost:8080/secure/attachmentzip/' + req.body.issue.id + ".zip", {
    auth: {
        username: '-',
        password: '-'
    },
    encoding: null // important to avoid utf8 conversion
})
.then(buffer => fs.writeFile('file.zip', buffer)) // fs.promises
.then(() => console.log('saved'))
.catch(console.error)
```

Although if you're downloading files, it's better to use streams specially if the file is big.

```js
const request = require('request'); // better to use request when using streams
const fs = require('fs');

request.get('http://localhost:8080/secure/attachmentzip/' + req.body.issue.id + ".zip", {
    auth: {
        username: '-',
        password: '-'
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.zip'))
```

**Note:** Without having being able to test that URL, can't give you an axios specific solution.

Comment: Thank you, both solutions have solved my problem. Minor correction on the first one,                     fs.writeFile("file.zip", buffer, function(err){console.log(err)});

Comment: You're welcome, I recommend using `fs.promises` to avoid the callback, check updated example.